# Is there an open-source implementation of the Dictionary Huffman compression algorithm?

Tags: compression, huffman-code, mobipocket

I'm working on a library to work with Mobipocket-format ebook files, and I have LZ77-style PalmDoc decompression and compression working. However, PalmDoc compression is only one of the two currently-used types of text compression being used on ebooks in the wild, the other being Dictionary Huffman aka huffcdic.

I've found a [couple](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#UyIFBCPuUZU/lib/mobiunpack.py) of [implementations](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#qaIkrkxVBaQ/fbreader/src/formats/pdb/HuffDecompressor.cpp) of the huffcdic decoding algorithm, but I'd like to be able to compress to the same format, and so far I haven't been able to find any examples of how to do that yet. Has someone else already figured this out and published the code?

Comment: What do you mean, you don't want to reverse engineer that decoding algorithm?!? :D

Comment: I think I *can*... but it'd be nice to have a reference implementation to work against :)

Answer (score 1):

i have been trying to use http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kovid/calibre/trunk/view/head:/src/calibre/ebooks/compression/palmdoc.c but compression doesnt produce identical results, & there are 3 - 4 descrepencies also read one related thread [LZ77 compression of palmdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632931/lz77-compression-of-palmdoc)